# how to know if the curve is intersect with the red line

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, curve, intersect

[image: Thank you !!!!please help me]

this curve is consist of these points. i want to know if the red line intersect with the curve. the red line is consist of PointA and PointB. what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct pos
{
    double x ;
    double y ;
};
struct line
{
    pos st ;
    pos end ;
};
int n ;
double Multiply(pos p1, pos p2, pos p0)
{
    return ( (p1.x - p0.x) * (p2.y - p0.y) - (p2.x - p0.x) * (p1.y - p0.y) );
}
bool iscross(line L1, line L2)
{
    return( (max(L1.st.x,   L1.end.x) >= min(L2.st.x, L2.end.x)) &&
        (max(L2.st.x,   L2.end.x) >= min(L1.st.x, L1.end.x)) &&
        (max(L1.st.y,   L1.end.y) >= min(L2.st.y, L2.end.y)) &&
        (max(L2.st.y,   L2.end.y) >= min(L1.st.y, L1.end.y)) &&
        (Multiply(L2.st, L1.end, L1.st) * Multiply(L1.end, L2.end, L1.st) >= 0) &&
        (Multiply(L1.st, L2.end, L2.st) * Multiply(L2.end, L1.end, L2.st) >= 0)
    );
}
```